# How to filter out an array of objects on a basis of a given param?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

I have this array:

```
[
  {
    "prod": {
      "a": "b",
      "mdh": "nui";
    },
    "prod_merchant": {
      "prod_delivery": "Express",
      "site": 45
    }
  },
  {
    "prod": {
      "a": "b",
      "mdh": "nui";
    },
    "prod_merchant": {
      "prod_delivery": "Scheduled",
      "site": 45
    }
  },
]
```

My code:

```
let prod_delivery = req.param('prod_delivery');
console.log(prod_delivery) // Express
GlobalServices.isDisabledAddToCart(filteredProductList, filters)
    .then(function(updatedProductList) //Under updatedProductList that whole array is coming
        {
            var output = updatedProductList.filter(function(x) {
                return x.prod_merchant.prod_delivery == prod_delivery.prod_delivery
            });

            console.log("output", output)
        }
```

Output:
output []

Basically, I want to get all the product details on the basis of prod_delivery from the array.

Comment: What's the value of `prod_delivery`?

Comment: In the array I have mentioned the value of prod_delivery , which is 
prod_delivery: "Express"
or 
prod_delivery: "Scheduled"

Comment: I'm taking about `let prod_delivery = req.param('prod_delivery');`

Comment: This is a param which I have taken, in which prod_delivery will be there

Comment: Can you log it and post the value for that? It's hard to help when we don't even know the inputs.

Comment: So if `prod_delivery` is a string, then `prod_delivery.prod_delivery` is `undefined`. No wonder you get an empty array.

Comment: I have edited with the log, it is coming whatever value i have given as parameter

Comment: Looking at the edit, since `prod_delivery` is a string, why are you doing `== prod_delivery.prod_delivery`? That seems to be your issue.

Comment: @trincot yep same hunch I had, `req.param` can potentially return an object though so I just wanted to be sure.

Comment: Can you please tell me how should i correct it, as I'm new to node and javascript

Comment: Replace `x.prod_merchant.prod_delivery == prod_delivery.prod_delivery` with `x.prod_merchant.prod_delivery == prod_delivery`. That should do it.

Comment: Thanks for solving it , at first I was giving "express" instead of "Express". And that's why getting null array.

Comment: x.prod_merchant.prod_delivery == prod_delivery solved this problem.
Solution by @AyushGupta worked .

Comment: You array has two semicolons -- it is not valid JSON.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `filter` for that:

```js
var products = [{
    "prod": {
      "a": "b",
      "mdh": "nui"
    },
    "prod_merchant": {
      "prod_delivery": "Express",
      "site": 45
    }
  },
  {
    "prod": {
      "a": "b",
      "mdh": "nui"
    },
    "prod_merchant": {
      "prod_delivery": "Scheduled",
      "site": 45
    }
  }
];

var prod_express = products.filter(product => product.prod_merchant.prod_delivery == 'Express');

console.log(prod_express);
```

Comment: Maybe with this answer one considers providing a case insensitive search/filter approach in order to solve the true/real issue the OP was experiencing (`express` vs `Express`). After all the OP's filter method was/is implemented correctly for case sensitivity / value equality.

Comment: @PeterSeliger I can see that from the comments, but I think that was more a bug then af feature. In any case OP could compare the lower case strings, like: `product.prod_merchant.prod_delivery.toLowerCase() == 'Express'.toLowerCase()`